# using 'groupby.count' with agg

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate

`df.head`

```
                Populous        Continents
Australia   2.331602e+07        Australia
Brazil      2.059153e+08        South America
Canada      3.523986e+07        North America
China      1.367645e+09         Asia
France     6.383735e+07         Europe
```

Above are the first 5 entries of my dataframe. 
I want to group them by Continents, then I want to perform some statistical analysis. I want to create a new dataframe with the Avg, Sum, STD of each Group's populous as well as the `count` of countries in each group, as its columns.

`new_df =df.groupby('Continents')['Populous'].agg({ 'Avg': np.average, 'Sum':np.sum, 'STD': np.std})`, takes care of three columns, but I don't know how to get `count` in there.  I tried including `'Size': count` , within the `agg` method, but it resulted in an error.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `'Size': 'count'` where count is a string .

Comment: Ah. This seems to work. So non-numpy functions work without converting function name to strings, but other functions require string conversion?

Comment: As a convinience, the pandas devs added string aliases for common functions used in `groupby`.  For example, your entire `agg` could be written `{'Avg': 'mean', 'Sum':'sum', 'STD': 'std'}`.  Note that there is a slight difference between `'mean'`, and `np.average`, in that `'mean'` ignores `NaN`, whereas `np.average` will return `NaN` if one is present.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'Size': len` or `'Size': 'count'` for this to work. However, as @DSM pointed out, `len` does count missing values whereas `'count'` doesn't.

Comment: `len` and `'count'` aren't the same-- `count` doesn't include null values but `len` does.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the note- I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might also find this useful:

```
df.groupby('Continents').Populous.describe().unstack()
```

Also see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547818/2336654) if you want more stats.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using `describe`, but I noticed it was missing `sum' so I gave up. However, it seems I can add my own stats.  Thanks for the link =)